# What language can I use to read directories and files from an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, filesystems

I'm continuing the project I talked about in another thread here, but at the moment I have stopped because I can't figure out how to dynamically add content to the page. It's supposed to be a webapp that runs locally (it won't be hosted on a domain).

I thought I'd be able to do it with JS, however I found out it can't read files for security reasons. **What I was planning to do** was get a list of all the files and folders inside a given directory (using JS), then append a div for each folder (with more stuff inside) inside the content area of my page. Seeing how I couldn't do that with JS, I thought maybe I could do it with PHP using the same approach, but I didn't like the idea of having to run xampp just for this... if there's a way to have PHP running without xampp and/or a server, then it'd be great, but so far I haven't found anything about that... except downloading PHP, but I have no clue how to "use" the console from the browser and then have it append the divs to the page, since the console and the browser are "separated".
To make it a little more clear: **is there a way to run PHP without a server, and if not, what other languages can I look up to?**

At this point I'd also like to know how websites such as clipchamp.com work. Do you guys have a clue about that?

Answer (score 1):

In order to run PHP, you'll indeed need a server with the right permissions on the folder.

For small local projects, I've seen Node.js used, the learning curve isn't too steep if you already know JS. Check out the `fs` module in Node for access to the filesystem.

Comment: This still requires a server if I understand correctly. But anyways whatever I do it looks like I need one as long as I'm dealing with dynamic content and browsers, so I guess I'll try looking into nodejs and then *hopefully* I can find a workaround in case I want other less tech-savvy (see: friends) people to be able to use this

Comment: You can encapsulate nodejs into a desktop app using Electron or something. But then you'd be better off using a browser extension.

Comment: No need to, already looking at node js and beginning to understand how it works, have a rough idea of what I should be doing and how I can make a workaround for the less tech-savvy friends I talked about :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I thought I'd be able to do it with JS, however I found out it can't read files for security reasons.

It can, just not when the JS itself is executing in a web browser. JS running in, for example, Windows Scripting Host or NodeJS would have no problems.

> if there's a way to have PHP running without xampp and/or a server

You can run PHP from the command line, but if you want the output to be rendered in a browser then you really need to be dealing with HTTP, which requires a server.

There is always the option of PHP's [built-in webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

> is there a way to run PHP without a server, and if not, what other languages can I look up to?

It doesn't matter what language you use. You'll find it hard to pick one that can't read the file system. They will all suffer from the same limitations when it comes to interacting with a web browser though. You need to be talking HTTP.

Comment: On quote#1: thanks, that cleared some misunderstadings. Stumbled upon NodeJS yesterday (don't remember how), going to give it a better look. Something useful yet easy to read about it?
On quote#2: not interested (possible compatibility reasons). Currently looking at CefSharp, but can't find documentation. So far managed to wrap the browser in a form. Tried feeding custom HTML (thought I'd try editing it later based on folders I found and feed it back) via LoadHTML, but it looks like it ignored CSS.
On quote#3: can you please elaborate on "need to be talking HTTP"?

Comment: 1. It still comes down to needing a server (if you want to present the results in a browser). I can't recommend any particular reading material. 3. Getting a web browser to load dynamically generated content means it has to make an HTTP request rather then read a static file. That requires an HTTP server to make the request to.

Comment: I think I understand now, thanks. I'll be looking into nodejs then, it looks like the better choice to me here.

Answer (score 0):

That is the whole concept of a browser. A browser can not give more permission to the system then the user of the browser does.
You have afaik two options: Use a server on the machine you want to manipulate (there are all kind of flavors, you can use nearly every language for building a server) or use/create a browser plugin that can do it (Silverlight can have access to the file system under some restrictions).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though I didn't understand at first. Everything's much more clear now that I gave a better look at node js :)

Comment: Everybody has to start somewhere and gain experience piece by piece. ;) I just wanted to tell you that your tool (browser) is not fit for the task you wanted to achieve (or at least you have to add other tools). Since you already made contact with JS I guess node.js is the easiest entry to how this stuff works.